# How to apply image to geo nodes instances?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, instances

as you can see in the image below, I'm instancing a number of rectangles on a plane:
[image: render of instancing blocks with geometry nodes]

What I'd like to do is add an image to the top of the blocks, so that when seen from above it shows the world (image with transparency). I've tried Project from View to unwrap it, but it only projects on the plane itself, not the instances. I've also tried Realise Instances, but this didn't seem to work either.

Is there way to do this and still have control over the movement of the blocks? My current node setup looks like this:
[image: geometry nodes setup to instance blocks on a plane]

Thanks for any help you can give!

Andy(:

Comment: You want an image-texture on the top surfaces of the blocks? Pixellated per block? Or continuous? It's still a little unclear what you want your result to look like.

Comment: Hi - yes, on top of the the blocks, and only visible on the blocks, not in between. Hope this explains it ok.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to only have the texture only on top, you can compare the normal's *z* in either GN or shaders.

Comment: Thanks @shmuel, I'll try this